# XJC error for XSD with 2 elements with same name but different case

Tags: xsd, xjc

I have xsd with 2 elements: "state" and "State". When I perform XJC using maven-jaxb2-plugin, I get the following error:

```
<xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
.
.
.
<xsd:element name="State" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />

SAXParseException2: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class
```

This is expected, since it tries to convert the element with "**S**tate" to "**s**tate" internally which causes the conflict with the already existing "state". My question is, is there a way to maintain case?

**NOTE: I know this is not ideal in the first place to have same element names, but unfortunately, I have no control over changing the XSD.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `jaxb:class` or `jaxb:factoryMethod` customizations to avoid naming collissions?

Something like:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='state']">
    <jaxb:factoryMethod name="LowerState"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```